# Go to div on page when i click on a buttom

Tags: html, onclick, goto

I Want my buttom to take the use to a serten place on the page. i was looking at some jquery but i would prefer to do it in HTML5 and css3 if it works. I also took a look at anchor tags but didnt get it to work with mu button.
`<button type="button" class="btn" >Contact-us</button>` 
and my page i want to go to `<div id="contact-us">`

Comment: You could do it with an `<a>`, but not `<button>`. You need to use Javascript to make clicking on a button do something.

Comment: You have `onclick` in the tags. You know that `onclick` is Javascript, right? But you said you don't want to use that.

Comment: ankers should be pretty perfect for this problem. If you wan't a smooth scroll take a look for jQuery solution e.g. smooth-scroll  plugin. Ankers example here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your div, or right above it you can use a link like such:

```
<a name="label"></a>
```

Later you can link to it with

```
<a href = yoururl#label">Click here</a>
```

This type of link is called an anchor, and will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment above, use an anker to an ID. If you wan't to keep the button style wrap it by an anker.

```
<a href="#anker1"><button type="button" class="btn">Contact-us</button></a>
<!-- content goes here -->
<div id="anker1">here we go, could also be empty...</div>
```

for a very nice effect with smooth scrolling you can easy add little jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b70xh8mg/1/